# How to define the height of a container to default value or nothing

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Container and an image inside the container. I want to define the height for the container depending on the type of photo. If it is in portrait then the height should be of a size. If it is in Landscape then i want it to be in default height(the one automatically assigned).

In the Example below consider the height is False(Landscape Photo)

```
Container(
  height: isPortrait
  ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.4
  : __________ , //  How to define something like do nothing

    child: ClipRRect(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
           child: Image.asset(image)
          ),
         ),
```

Comment: why you are not using mediaquery for landscape also

Comment: Cause for Landscape i am planning to add text in place of image if i want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since height is a double, there is no real way of setting it to "default" other than not assigning it. You could try something like this:

```
isPortrait
          ? Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              child: RestOfContent())
          : Container(
              child: RestOfContent(),
            ),
```

`RestOfContent` Would be a Builder/Widget with the rest of your code. This way you don't have to write duplicate code.